What are the git commands to rebase a child-branch whose parent branch has been rebased?
This has happened multiple times where we have a devel branch on which a large feature (feature/one branch) is being worked by multiple people. Each developer branches off of feature/one and performs a sub-task. Periodically, the sub-tasks are merged into feature/one.

Initial Commit Graph.
Branches are: devel is off of main, feature/one is off of devel, and more-work is off of feature/one.  Since main has no impact on the remainder of this question it is not shown in any subsequent commit graphs.
o--o--o (main) 
       \ 
        A---B---C (devel) 
             \ 
              D---E---F (feature/one) 
                   \ 
                    G---H (more-work) # one sub-task.

The feature/one branch is ready to be merged so it must first be rebased.  To do this the git rebase command is used as follows:
git checkout devel 
git pull 
git checkout feature/one 
git rebase devel 

These command ensure you have the latest devel branch and then you rebase onto it.

The resulting git commit graph is:
A---B---C (devel) 
     \   \ 
      \   D2--E2--F2 (rebased feature/one) 
       \ 
        D---E---F (original feature/one, now detached from feature/one branch) 
             \ 
              G---H (more-work) 

This gives the desired result and is the normal case I’ve used many times successfully.
NOTE: The hash D2 represents the commit D but with a new hash, similarly with E2 and F2.
Next, I want to merge more-work into feature/one.
IMPORTANT NOTE:  IMO cherry-pick would be simpler to achieve the desired result.
What follows are the multiple (2 steps) required to allow git rebase –onto feature/one to be used. This means that more-work needs to be rebased onto original feature/one first (to include the F commit), and then onto rebased feature/one branch.

First rebase onto original feature/one to include the F commit.  I'm not sure of the git command to do this so it is not shown, but the resulting git commit graph would look like this:
A---B---C (devel) 
    |\   \ 
    | \   D2--E2--F2 (rebased feature/one) 
    |  \ 
    |   D---E---F (original feature/one, now detached from feature/one branch) 
    |        \ 
    \         G---H (more-work) 
     \    
      D3---E3---F3 (original feature/one rehashed a 2nd time) 
                 \ 
                  G2---H2 (more-work (rebased)) 

At this point, the more-work rebased branch now includes the change made in hash F which allows the use of the git rebase --onto feature/one command as follows
git rebase --onto feature/one F3-hash more-work 


After the above git command we have the following graph
A---B---C (devel) 
    |\   \ 
    | \   D2--E2--F2 (feature/one after rebase) 
    |  \           \ 
    |   \           G3---H3 (more-work (rebased-2nd-time)) 
    |    \  
    |     D---E---F (original feature/one, now detached from feature/one branch) 
    |          \ 
    \           G---H (more-work) 
     \    
      D3---E3---F3 (original feature/one rehashed a 2nd time) 
                 \ 
                  G2---H2 (more-work (rebased)) 



Is my understanding of how to rebase a child-branch whose parent-branch has been rebased correct?
The following are relevant links I've found to form my understanding of how git rebase works.

Is there a way to rebase a child branch after the parent has been rebased? - this question/answer different from the question here in that the child-branch is not "up to date" with the parent branch at the time the parent is rebased. And my belief is the multiple rebases are needed as I illustrate in my commit graphs.

How can I change my parent branch? This is documented in the git documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase and shows how the topic branch can be moved from the next branch (aka devel in my example) to the master branch.
 o---o---o---o---o  master
         \
          o---o---o---o---o  next
                           \
                            o---o---o  topic

The biggest difference between this and my question is that my example does not have topic coming off of the HEAD of next.
The command to rebase onto master is simple.
git rebase --onto master next topic

which results in
    o---o---o---o---o  master
        |            \
        |             o'--o'--o'  topic
         \
          o---o---o---o---o  next



Other searches were answering other questions

Rebasing a branch that has been branched from - not relevant.

git rebase master with child branches - this appears different (to me)



There is no difference to "changing a parent branch". You want to change the parent branch: from the pre-rebased version of your branch (F3) to the post-rebased version of your branch. A branch is nothing more than a name for a commit.


Is my understanding of how to rebase a child-branch who’s parent-branch has been rebased correct?

Correct? kind of. Ideal? no.
The rebase of more-work onto rebased feature/one can and should be done in one pass. This is the exact scenario for which rebase --onto was created.
Initial situation
* 9a7c139 (HEAD -> more-work) H
* 922d375 G
| * 978c327 (feature/one) F
|/
* bce6cab E
* 3cf018e D
| * 9c2aeeb (devel) C
|/
* 0c5017f B
* 8914d3a A
* fbc5771 (master) Initial commit

Rebasing feature/one on devel
git switch feature/one && git rebase devel

* 6f50942 (HEAD -> feature/one) F
* 3cad97b E
* d0f8a97 D
* 9c2aeeb (devel) C
| * 9a7c139 (more-work) H
| * 922d375 G
| * bce6cab E
| * 3cf018e D
|/
* 0c5017f B
* 8914d3a A
* fbc5771 (master) Initial commit

Rebasing more-work onto feature/one
E_sha1=bce6cab 
git rebase --onto feature/one $E_sha1 more-work

* 6cb28df (HEAD -> more-work) H
* 1fc20f8 G
* 6f50942 (feature/one) F
* 3cad97b E
* d0f8a97 D
* 9c2aeeb (devel) C
* 0c5017f B
* 8914d3a A
* fbc5771 (master) Initial commit


Nice touch using the git log to show this "in action".

Kind of, git rebase --onto feature/one E more-work is the canonical way to do it and you don't need two "steps" to do the rebase. Rebase the first branch (git rebase deve feature/one), then rebase the second branch (see first rebase command). The command means "take commits between F and more-work and create copies of them on top of feature/one, then update the more-work branch to point to the new commits". git rebase --onto feature/one F more-work would give exactly the same result, because both commit ranges E..more-work and F..more-work describe the same set of commits (i.e. G and H).
So starting with your initial history:
o--o--o (main) 
       \ 
        A--B--C (devel) 
            \ 
             D--E--F (feature/one) 
                 \ 
                  G--H (more-work)

to get to the desired final history:
o--o--o (main) 
       \ 
        A--B--C (devel) 
               \ 
                D--E--F (feature/one) 
                       \ 
                        G--H (more-work)

run the following commands in order:
git rebase devel feature/one
git rebase --onto feature/one E more-work
# or, same result: git rebase --onto feature/one F more-work


You might also try a simple git rebase feature/one more-work – Git is usually smart enough to figure out which commits are already part of the new parent.
The alternative is rebasing both branches at the same time if you already know that one branch is a direct descendant of the other – and the other branch is fully contained in yours:
A--B--C (devel) 
    \ 
     D--E--F (feature/one) 
            \ 
             G--H (more-work)

To both rebase them to the new upstream:
git rebase --update-refs devel more-work`

This will rebase all commits between devel and more-work, and update your feature/one ref (i.e. branch). The resulting history will be:
A--B--C (devel) 
       \ 
        D2--E2--F2 (rebased feature/one) 
                  \ 
                   G2---H2 (rebased more-work)


The whole thing is really not all that different from "changing the parent branch": initially the parent "branch" (a branch is nothing more than a name for a commit) of more-work was commit E (pre-rebase) and you are trying to change it to commit F2 (post-rebase). It doesn't really matter that there are other commits that are descendants of your branch or your old (or new) branch.

But the hash for F3-hash doesn't yet exist when you run git rebase --onto feature/one F3-hash more-work, unless you've done the 1st rebase.  Are you suggesting this: git rebase --onto feature/one F more-work?  If so I'm not sure how GIT would know I want to rebase commits G & H.

@PatS sorry, you are absolutely correct; I copied the hash from the wrong ASCII art from the question (there were too many :)). I have updated my answer with some clarification, I hope that it is clearer now. Git knows you want to rebase commits G and H because you tell it exactly that with the command: G and H are the commits between F and more-work (F..more-work, or ^F more-work, resolves to G and H).

Excellent update.  Thank you for the clarification.  I had already selected another answer as the "answer" because it does state what you are now stating.  If I could select two answers I would. Including the update-refs is another new thing that I wasn't aware of.  Thanks again!

When you said: Git is usually smart enough to figure out which commits are already part of the new parent.  I created a test repo to experiment and I was surprised to find that git did find common parent commits and ignored them (still wondering how it did that).

@PatS if a commit that is being rebased has the same changeset as one of the commits in the parents, it will be skipped.

I've tried to find out how git knows that the commit is the same and I'm not sure how it knows.  Does git  use the SHA-1 of the contents of the change (aka the file changed) to determine that a commit is the same as a prior commit?  I thought it happen because the .git object store still had the detached commits, but I ran a git gc command to delete all objects and git still figured it out, so I learned that git is able to figure this out with other information stored within a commit.

@PatS I haven't looked at the implementation, but I always assumed it will use the patch id. Git can compute the patch id before appyling a commit and if the same patch already exists upstream, it will be ignored.
